# Creating a thread-safe, static Dictionary in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, thread-safety

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application which includes a static Dictionary. This is problematic because the Dictionary class is not thread-safe, which may cause trouble when it is accessed by concurrent web requests. I am considering wrapping the dictionary like this:

```
public class DataDictionary
{
    private object Lock = new object();
    private int NextId = 0;
    private Dictionary<int, Data> DataLog = new Dictionary<int, Data> {};

    public int Add(Data data)
    {
        lock (Lock)
        {
            var id = NextId++;
            DataLog.Add(id, data);
            return id;
        }
    }

    public Data GetData (int id)
    {
        lock (Lock)
        {
            return DataLog[id];
        }
    }

    public void Remove(int id)
    {
        lock (Lock)
        {
            DataLog.Remove(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Will this allow safe access to the Dictionary by concurrent web requests? If not, what can I do to facilitate similar behavior safely?

Comment: And what when your AppPool recycles?  Or when you need to scale out?  `static` is always a lame cop-out.

Comment: What about a ConcurrentDictionary? There's documentation on it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx). First line of documentation reads `Represents a thread-safe collection of key/value pairs that can be accessed by multiple threads concurrently.`

Comment: @HenkHolterman Won't have to be concerned with scalability - the application is only used internally, and by <10 individuals. If that changes I can guarantee this app will be long dead.

Comment: That leaves the issue of recycling, what is the required lifetime of your data?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I've never actually run into a situation where recycling mattered... I've been doing some reading, and it looks like the concern here is reinstantiation of the static instance, which is definitely a problem. I'll have to consider alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

What about a ConcurrentDictionary, there's documentation on it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx).

The first line of this documentation states:

> Represents a thread-safe collection of key/value pairs that can be accessed by multiple threads concurrently.